# Run-time error 1004 with vba adding hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, runtime-error

Can someone please help me in my time of need. I have created a `userform` which is entering in a `hyperlink` dependent on dropdowns from a `listbox`.

Despite the hyperlink actually going in when the submit button is pressed, I am still receiving the error message of

> Run-Time error 1004. Application-defined or object defined error.

When I debug `ws.cells(iRow, 4)` is the line highlighted

```
Private Sub Comm1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("QttOutlay")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("LookupVals")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

Set rng = ws.Cells(iRow)    

    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = RmRef.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = RetMod.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=rng, Address:=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RetMod.Value, ws2.Range("A:B"), 2, False), TextToDisplay:="Info")
    ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = OrdCod.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = hmm.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = lmm.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = rdtype.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = dtt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Wtt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Qt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = LPc.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Dt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = (LPc.Value * Dt.Value) * Qt.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [`Hyperlinks.Add` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx) returns a hyperlink object which you are trying to assign to a cells value: `ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(…)`. That won't work.
2. I guess that `ws.Cells(iRow, 4)` is meant to be the anchor of the hyperlink like: `Anchor:=ws.Cells(iRow, 4)`

So instead of

```
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=rng, Address:=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RetMod.Value, ws2.Range("A:B"), 2, False), TextToDisplay:="Info")
```

you should replace the whole line with something like this

```
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(iRow, 4), Address:=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RetMod.Value, ws2.Range("A:B"), 2, False), TextToDisplay:="Info"
```